# The equivalence condition for a linear map $T:V\longrightarrow Z$ with $W\subset \ker(T)$ between normed vector space to be continuous.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, normed-spaces

Let $V$ be a normed vector space and $W$ be a closed linear subspace. The quotient norm on $V/W$ is defined by $$\|[x]\|_{V/W}:=\inf_{y\in W}\|x-y\|_{V}.$$ (As $W$ is closed, the "norm" is indeed a norm)

We also define the quotient map $Q:V\longrightarrow V/W$. I am learning several properties of the map $Q$, so far, I have proved that

> 1. $\|Q\|_{op}=1$, bounded (hence continuous).
> 2. $Q:V\longrightarrow V/W$ is an open map, by proving $Q(B_{r}^{V}(x))=B_{r}^{V/W}([x]).$
> 3. $A\subset V/W$ is open if and only if $Q^{-1}(A)$ is open in V.

Now, I want to use 1 and 2 to prove the following statement:

> For every vector space $Z$, a linear map $T:V\longrightarrow Z$ with $W\subset \ker(T)$ is continuous if and only if the unique map $\tilde{T}$ such that $T=\tilde{T}\circ Q$ is continuous.

---

By the description of $\tilde{T}$, it should be the map $\tilde{T}:V/W\longrightarrow Z$. But then I don't know where to start. How is this related to $\ker(T)$?

What should I do? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The map $\overline{T}:V/W\to Z$ should be defined by

$$ \overline{T}\Big( v+W \Big):= T(v)  $$

as all maps from the quotient space are.

Since composing continuous maps is continuous, one implication should be obvious. So you only have to show that $\overline{T}$ is also continuous if $T$ is.

So take an open subset $U\subset Z$ and we want to show that $\overline{T}^{-1}[U]$ is open in $V/W$. ${T}^{-1}[U]$ is open by assumption in $V$. Since $Q$ is open, you know that $ Q\circ T^{-1}[U] $ is open in $V/W$. Now just verify that $Q\circ T^{-1}[U]=\overline{T}^{-1}[U]$, and you're done.

Comment: Great! To prove the last equality, since the digram commute, we have $T(U)=\tilde{T}\circ Q(U)$ and thus $$T^{-1}(U)=Q^{-1}\circ\tilde{T}^{-1}(U).$$ Since $Q$ is surjective, the above gives us $$Q(T^{-1}(U))=(Q\circ Q^{-1})(\tilde{T}^{-1}(U))=\tilde{T}^{-1}(U).$$ Am I right?

Comment: Also, in the first line of you last paragraph, do you mean we need to show that $\tilde{T}^{-1}(U)$ is open in $V/W$? I know perhaps it open in $V/W$ is equivalent to open in $V$ (I forgot about the details of quotient topology), just curious.

Comment: @JacobsonRadical No, you're right. I had a typo.

Comment: Great. Thanks for the nice answer!

Comment: @JacobsonRadical You're welcome.